# Access to Prism Xamarin Forms injects outside viewmodels

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I am currently developing a Xamarin Forms app and am in the process of reworking it to work with Prism.  I'm really trying to adhere to MVVM design patterns (I'm trying to grow as an amateur developer and learn how to use them).

1) Is it improper from a MVVM design pattern perspective to utilize messaging services (Prism's EventAggregator) and UI interactions (Prism's PageDialogService) outside of VMs?  I've written several "services" that are called from the VM and have found a need to access both messaging and UI services.  As one example, The VM calls a service, the service retrieves and processes some data, ask a question to the user based upon those calculations and then continue to finish processing returning the desired value.  To be proper, should control be returned back to the VM to "just" ask the question?

2) If it's not verboten, is it possible to access the services outside of VMs?  It does not readily appear to me that I can inject them into the constructor of the service. Is it okay to "pass" them into the service's function I'm calling along with other parameters?  That just seems un... MVVM-ish?

**Update:**

I'm not sure all my steps were necessary, but with the help below I got it working.  First I converted my singleton service into an interface (IMyService) and an implementing class (MyService).  Next, I overrode ConfigureContainer in App.xaml.cs and called `Container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());`

I could then inject IMyService, just like IEventAggregator and IPageDialogService into my ViewModels and I could also inject those services into the public constructor of my implementing class (MyService).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ad 1) the event aggregator is meant primarily for UI, but you can use it as message bus in other parts of the app, too, if you don't need the more advanced features of a "real" message bus.

ad 2) unity will happily inject dependencies into services that are themselves dependencies of view models or other services. That's what a dependency injection container does :-)

Comment: Actually the event aggregator is meant for non-UI fire and forget messaging.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer made me realize that I need to register the service with the Unity container (I'm learning...).  This allowed me to find this post that is along the same lines as what I need: [Injecting a property into a singleton service in Prism (Unity, MVVM)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565473/injecting-a-property-into-a-singleton-service-in-prism-unity-mvvm)